# Accessing a public google sheet's data directly from client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get cell values of a public google spread sheet ?

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1vW01Y46DcpCC7aKLIUwV_W4RXLbeukVwF-G9AA7P7R0/values/A1A4?key=abcdef
```

returns 403.
I also sent the **Referrer** in Postman : `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Requests from referer Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36 are blocked.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "consumer": "projects/666",
                    "service": "sheets.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to access a public sheet's data directly from client-side JavaScript.

No round-trips to the server. I remember this was possible some 10 years ago but am unable to locate the docs.

Comment: The sheet ID you have provided is not available.

Comment: I deleted after I got it working with JavaScript key and sheetID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the public spreadsheet by json endpoint

```
var id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var gid = '1111111111111';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
```

Take a slice

```
data.substring(47).slice(0, -2)
```

and parse the json

### direct link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n-rjSYb63Z2jySS3-M0BQ78vu8DTPOjG-SZM4i8IxXI/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=0

### example by gas

```
function getEndpointJson(){
  var id = '1n-rjSYb63Z2jySS3-M0BQ78vu8DTPOjG-SZM4i8IxXI';
  var gid = '0';
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=${gid}`).getContentText();
  var jsonString = txt.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var table = []
  var row = []
  json.cols.forEach(colonne => row.push(colonne.label))
  table.push(row)
  json.rows.forEach(r => {
    var row = []
    r.c.forEach(cel => {
        try{var value = cel.f ? cel.f : cel.v}
        catch(e){var value = ''}
        row.push(value)
      }
    )
    table.push(row)
    }
  )
  return (table)
}
```

### example by html page

For instance on html page (you have to store it in outside server)

```
<html>
<title>Google Sheets json endpoint V4</title>
<author>Mike Steelson</author>
<style>
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
th,td{border: 1px solid black;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="json">json here</div>
<script>
var id = '1n-rjSYb63Z2jySS3-M0BQ78vu8DTPOjG-SZM4i8IxXI';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=myItems(data.substring(47).slice(0, -2))  
  );
function myItems(jsonString){
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table><tr>'
  json.table.cols.forEach(colonne => table += '<th>' + colonne.label + '</th>')
  table += '</tr>'
  json.table.rows.forEach(ligne => {
    table += '<tr>'
    ligne.c.forEach(cellule => {
        try{var valeur = cellule.f ? cellule.f : cellule.v}
        catch(e){var valeur = ''}
        table += '<td>' + valeur + '</td>'
      }
    )
    table += '</tr>'
    }
  )
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}           
</script>
</body></html>
```

*The sheet ID you have provided is wrong.*

Answer (score 1):

Based on [some brief research](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey), there are available JS libraries that let you access GSheets data, but Google requires an API key:

> Requests to the Google Sheets API for public data must be accompanied by an identifier, which can be an API key or an access token.

Here's an example library:

[gsheets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsheets) - Get public Google Sheets as plain JavaScript/JSON.

Comment: `?key` is there in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is to remove the restrictions in Google Cloud Console

[image: Answer is to remove the restrictions in Google Cloud Console]

Answer (score 1):

Consider using this library.

https://github.com/fureweb-com/public-google-sheets-parser

You can use it like this way:

```js
const PublicGoogleSheetsParser = require('public-google-sheets-parser')

const spreadsheetId = '10WDbAPAY7Xl5DT36VuMheTPTTpqx9x0C5sDCnh4BGps'

// 1. You can pass spreadsheetId when instantiating the parser:
const parser = new PublicGoogleSheetsParser(spreadsheetId)
parser.parse().then((items) => {
  // items should be [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]
})
```

Comment: Good, but could you please add a disclaimer that you made the library?